# Lucene sort by score and then modified date

Tags: lucene

I have three fields in my document

1. Title
2. Content
3. Modified Date

So when I search a `term` it's giving by results sorted by `score`

Now I would like to further sort the results with same score based upon on `modifiedDate` i.e. showing recent documents on top with the same score.

I tried sort by score, modified date but it's not working. Anyone can point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done simply by defining a Sort:

```java
Sort sort = new Sort(
    SortField.FIELD_SCORE, 
    new SortField("myDateField", SortField.Type.STRING));
indexSearcher.search(myQuery, numHits, sort);
```

Two possible gotchas here:

- You should make sure your date is indexed in a searchable, and sortable, form.  Generally, the best way to accomplish this is to convert it using [`DateTools`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/DateTools.html?is-external=true).
- The field used for sorting must be indexed, and should *not* be analyzed (a `StringField`, for instance).  Up to you whether it is stored.

So adding the date field might look something like:

```java
Field dateField = new StringField(
    "myDateField", 
    DateTools.DateToString(myDateInstance, DateTools.Resolution.MINUTE),
    Field.Store.YES);
document.add(dateField);
```

Note: You can also index dates as a numeric field using `Date.getTime()`.  I prefer the `DateTools` string approach, as it provides some nicer tools for handling them, particularly with regards to precision, but either way can work.

Comment: Sort is not suited here, because it gives a recent documents on top. As said in question, we need first sort documents by relevance, and if documents have equal score then sort by time.

Comment: @AlexanderKuznetsov - See the sort declaration in my answer.  The first `SortField` in the ctor is [`SortField.FIELD_SCORE`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/core/index.html?org/apache/lucene/search/SortField.html), so it *will* sort by score first, then by the date field.

Comment: Thanks, for clarification.

Comment: Do you know how to reverse `SortField.FIELD_SCORE`? It is easy for a new `SortField`, by adding the boolean reverse. But I can't figure out how to do it for `FIELD_SCORE`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a custom collector for solving this problem. It will sort result by score, then by timestamp. In this collector you should retrieve the timestamp value for second sorting. See class below

```java
public class CustomCollector extends TopDocsCollector<ScoreDocWithTime> {

    ScoreDocWithTime pqTop;

    // prevents instantiation
    public CustomCollector(int numHits) {
        super(new HitQueueWithTime(numHits, true));
        // HitQueue implements getSentinelObject to return a ScoreDoc, so we know
        // that at this point top() is already initialized.
        pqTop = pq.top();
    }

    @Override
    public LeafCollector getLeafCollector(LeafReaderContext context)
            throws IOException {
        final int docBase = context.docBase;
        final NumericDocValues modifiedDate =
                DocValues.getNumeric(context.reader(), "modifiedDate");

        return new LeafCollector() {
            Scorer scorer;


            @Override
            public void setScorer(Scorer scorer) throws IOException {
                this.scorer = scorer;
            }

            @Override
            public void collect(int doc) throws IOException {
                float score = scorer.score();

                // This collector cannot handle these scores:
                assert score != Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
                assert !Float.isNaN(score);

                totalHits++;
                if (score <= pqTop.score) {
                    // Since docs are returned in-order (i.e., increasing doc Id), a document
                    // with equal score to pqTop.score cannot compete since HitQueue favors
                    // documents with lower doc Ids. Therefore reject those docs too.
                    return;
                }
                pqTop.doc = doc + docBase;
                pqTop.score = score;
                pqTop.timestamp = modifiedDate.get(doc);
                pqTop = pq.updateTop();
            }

        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean needsScores() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Also to do second sorting you need add to ScoreDoc an additional field

```java
public class ScoreDocWithTime extends ScoreDoc {
    public long timestamp;

    public ScoreDocWithTime(long timestamp, int doc, float score) {
        super(doc, score);
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public ScoreDocWithTime(long timestamp, int doc, float score, int shardIndex) {
        super(doc, score, shardIndex);
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

and create a custom priority queue to support this

```java
public class HitQueueWithTime extends PriorityQueue<ScoreDocWithTime> {

    public HitQueueWithTime(int numHits, boolean b) {
        super(numHits, b);
    }

    @Override
    protected ScoreDocWithTime getSentinelObject() {
        return new ScoreDocWithTime(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean lessThan(ScoreDocWithTime hitA, ScoreDocWithTime hitB) {
        if (hitA.score == hitB.score)
            return (hitA.timestamp == hitB.timestamp) ?
                    hitA.doc > hitB.doc :
                    hitA.timestamp < hitB.timestamp;
        else
            return hitA.score < hitB.score;

    }
}
```

After this you can search result as you need. See example below

```java
public class SearchTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer());
        Directory directory = new RAMDirectory();
        IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, indexWriterConfig);

        addDoc(indexWriter, "w1", 1000);
        addDoc(indexWriter, "w1", 3000);
        addDoc(indexWriter, "w1", 500);
        addDoc(indexWriter, "w1 w2", 1000);
        addDoc(indexWriter, "w1 w2", 3000);
        addDoc(indexWriter, "w1 w2", 2000);
        addDoc(indexWriter, "w1 w2", 5000);

        final IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(indexWriter, false);
        IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
        BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
        query.add(new TermQuery(new Term("desc", "w1")), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
        query.add(new TermQuery(new Term("desc", "w2")), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

        CustomCollector results = new CustomCollector(100);
        indexSearcher.search(query, results);
        TopDocs search = results.topDocs();
        for (ScoreDoc sd : search.scoreDocs) {
            Document document = indexReader.document(sd.doc);
            System.out.println(document.getField("desc").stringValue() + " " + ((ScoreDocWithTime) sd).timestamp);
        }

    }

    private static void addDoc(IndexWriter indexWriter, String decs, long modifiedDate) throws IOException {
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new TextField("desc", decs, Field.Store.YES));
        doc.add(new LongField("modifiedDate", modifiedDate, Field.Store.YES));
        doc.add(new NumericDocValuesField("modifiedDate", modifiedDate));
        indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
    }
}
```

Program will output following results

```
w1 w2 5000
w1 w2 3000
w1 w2 2000
w1 w2 1000
w1 3000
w1 1000
w1 500
```

P.S. this solution for Lucene 5.1